# What kind of RAM does a 2010 motherboard support?

Tags: motherboard, desktop-computer, ddr

Thanks for Zeiss Ikon' s comment.
A: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02014355

---

I have an old computer. The motherboard is made in 2010.

It is missing a RAM card so I bought a DDR3 1600 RAM.
But the motherboard does not support it.

What kind of RAM is suitable for a 2010 motherboard?
Thanks.

EDIT:
I cannot start Windows, so using software is not a solution.

[image]

Comment: Please add a picture of the RAM slot, or the model of motherboard you have. My guess is that you're probably looking for DDR2.

Comment: Look at the specifications for the motherboard.

Comment: Google the exact motherboard model number and you'll very quickly find the RAM supported, along with anything else you're likely to want to know.

Comment: guys, software does not help because I cannot start windows.

Comment: There is more than one answer on the marked duplicate, and at least a couple contain information on how to visually identify the RAM.  There is no way we can tell you what RAM "a motherboard from 2010" takes, as there were only about 500 (give or take) motherboard models made in 2010. Provide the make and model, and if you can do that, you can look it up online yourself.

Comment: @ll55 - You never mentioned that in the original revision of your question.  While your screenshot helps, it does not provide us the required information, we need to know what CPU you have installed in your system at the very least.

Comment: There are 4 major DDR revisions, each with two DIMM module form factors (desktop and laptop) and then at least 5 speed revisions within each of the revisions. What is supported by any random board in 2010 is going to be guesswork. Look at your motherboard for any large writing that looks like a model number. That will be the only way to find out what your particular board supports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HWiNFO to check what your system already uses / needs.
If anyone should have any chance of helping, you should by very least provide model number and make of your motherboard.
HWiNFO can be found here:
https://www.fosshub.com/HWiNFO.html

just download the portable edition and run it.

Comment: software is not helping.